# How to scrape multiple pages with an unchanging URL - Python 3

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I recently got in touch with web scraping and tried to web scrape various pages. For now, I am trying to scrape the following site - http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList

So far I've used selenium to get the longitude and latitude scraped. However, my code right now only extracts the first page. I know there is a dynamic web scraping that executes javascript and loads different pages, but had hard time trying to find a right solution. I was wondering if there's a way to access the other 49 pages or so, because when I click next page the URL does not change because it is set, so I cannot just iterate over a different URL each time

Following is my code so far:

```
import os
import requests
import csv
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.find_all('div',class_='re_RNew'):
    name = row.find('p',class_='re_NameNew').string
    info = row.find('input').get('value')
    location = info.split('|')
    location_data = location[0].split(',')
    longitude = location_data[0]
    latitude = location_data[1]
    print(longitude, latitude)
```

Thank you so much for helping out. Much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Steps to get the data:

Open the developer tools in your browser (for Google Chrome it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). Now, go to the `XHR` tab which is located inside the `Network` tab.

[image]

After doing that, click on the next page button. You'll see the following file.

[image]

Click on that file. In the **General** block, you'll see these 2 things that we need.

[image]

Scrolling down, in the **Form Data** tab, you can see the 3 variables as

[image]

Here, you can see that changing the value of `pageIndex` will give all the pages required.

Now, that we've got all the required data, we can write a `POST` method for the URL `http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList/Index` using the above data.

## Code:

I'll show you the code to scrape first 2 pages, you can scrape any number of pages you want by changing the `range()`.

```
for page_no in range(1, 3):
    data = {
        'pageIndex': page_no,
        'pageSize': 10,
        'keyword': '输入餐厅地址或餐厅名称'
    }
    page = requests.post('http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList/Index', data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    print('PAGE', page_no)
    for row in soup.find_all('div',class_='re_RNew'):
        name = row.find('p',class_='re_NameNew').string
        info = row.find('input').get('value')
        location = info.split('|')
        location_data = location[0].split(',')
        longitude = location_data[0]
        latitude = location_data[1]
        print(longitude, latitude)
```

**Output:**

```
PAGE 1
31.085877 121.399176
31.271117 121.587577
31.098122 121.413396
31.331458 121.440183
31.094581 121.503654
31.270737000 121.481178000
31.138214 121.386943
30.915685 121.482079
31.279029 121.529255
31.168283 121.283322
PAGE 2
31.388674 121.35918
31.231706 121.472644
31.094857 121.219961
31.228564 121.516609
31.235717 121.478692
31.288498 121.521882
31.155139 121.428885
31.235249 121.474639
30.728829 121.341429
31.260372 121.343066
```

---

**Note:** You can change the results per page by changing the value of `pageSize` (currently it's 10).