# Dynamic Web Scraping in Python with unchanging URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, dynamic

I followed some previously encountered issues on stackoverflow but none of them completely resolves my issue.

I am trying to webscrape https://www.todywallaauctions.com/Results.aspx a coin auction website . I was able to dynamically web scrape the first page but not able to web scrape the remaining pages.

I followed the steps mentioned in  url [How to scrape multiple pages with an unchanging URL - Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985758/how-to-scrape-multiple-pages-with-an-unchanging-url-python-3?rq=1)

On todywallaauctions we don't have Form Data as mentioned in above example.

It access URL https://www.todywallaauctions.com/Results.aspx/getSearchResult when we change pages but doesn't have page indexing info.

What URL should I use to access the second page  ?

Comment: it uses JavaScript to load part of HTML from server and replace only this part of HTML in browser - there is no (full) second page. Use `getSearchResult` to get this part of HTML and scrape information from this part. BTW: it use parameters like `{'pageSize':'15','pageTop':'11','whereCondition':'; @MotherCategory = Coins & Paper Money'}` when it uses  `getSearchResult`

Comment: What url should I pass for scrapping? https://www.todywallaauctions.com/Results.aspx/getSearchResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` which uses url `getSearchResult` to load `XML` from server and then it generates HTML which it replaces on page. So finally you get second page but this page doesn't have own URL and it doesn't exist as full HTML.

---

You have to create `POST` request to url `getSearchResult` and send page number as `'pageTop'` in JSON data similar to

```
{'pageSize':'15','pageTop':'1','whereCondition':'; @MotherCategory = Coins & Paper Money'}
```

It will send back `JSON` data with one field `"d"` which has `XML` with all data. And then you can use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to search data in `XML`.

BTW: text with `XML` has names with some uppercase chars - like `ShortDesc` - but code needs lowercase chars - `shortdesc`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.todywallaauctions.com/Results.aspx/getSearchResult'

payload = {
    'pageSize':'15',
    'pageTop': '1',
    'whereCondition':'; @MotherCategory = Coins & Paper Money'
}

for page in range(1, 4):
    print('---', page, '---')

    payload['pageTop'] = str(page)
    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    #print(r.status_code)

    data = r.json()
    #print(data.keys())

    text = data['d']
    #print(text[:500])

    soup = BS(text)
    for item in soup.find_all('dtlotdata'):
        description = item.find('shortdesc')
        print('>', description.get_text(strip=True).strip())
```

Result:

```
--- 1 ---
> Rupees 100, 1960, signed P. C. Bhattacharya
> Rupees 2, set of 36 notes with different dates and signatures of all varieties
> George VI, Rupees 5, 2nd issue, 1947, signed C. D. Deshmukh
> Burma, George VI, Rupees 5, 1945, signed C. D. Deshmukh
> George VI, Rupees 5, 1st Issue, 1938, signed J. B. Taylor
> George VI, Rupees 2, 1943, signed J. B. Taylor
> George VI, Rupee 1, 1944
> George V, Rupees 5, 1st issue, 1925
> Embossed Postcard with impression of German East Africa Coins
> Indore State, Silver coat of Arms
> Proof Stamp Ingot, Silver 0.6g, Scinde Dawk, ½ Anna stamp of 1851. Rare.
> Stamp Ingot, Silver 12g, Indo Portuguese, 5 Reis stamp of Maria II. Rare.
> Proof Sterling Silver Ingot, 22g, Aden, Rupees 10 stamp of George VI. Rare.
> Proof Sterling Silver Ingot, 16g, Burma, Rupees 2 stamp of George VI. Rare.
> Proof Sterling Silver Ingot, 18g, Rupees 5 stamp of Queen Victoria. Rare.
--- 2 ---
> Proof Sterling Silver Ingot, 22g, Rupees 25 stamp of George V. Rare.
> Silver Token, 10g, Small Savings, Rajasthan Post Office
> Gold Token, 20g, India Post logo
> Indo Portuguese, Large Bronze Medal
> First day cover with hand stamp of Calicut 3.10.75
> An old Stamp Box to keep postage stamps, 1930s
> Copper Badges (4), circa 1950’s, four different
> Indo Portuguese, Large Bronze Medal, 360g
> Mahatma Gandhi, Silver Medallion, 38.73g
> Mahatma Gandhi, Gold Medal, 31.16g
> Mahatma Gandhi, Silver Medallion, 38.73g
> Silver Medallion, 29.16g
> Azad Hind / Tamgah-i-Azadi Medal, Medal
> Vir-i-Hind / Warrior of India an Azad Hind Order, 2nd Class Star Badge
> Sher-i-Hind / Tiger of India an Azad Hind Order
--- 3 ---
> Bhavnagar, Star shaped Brass Badge
> Gulmarg Golf Club, Silver Medal
> George VI Coronation Medal, Silver, 83.94g, 12th May 1937
> Silver Jubilee Medal of George V and Queen Mary, Silver, 15.58g
> George V Coronation, Silver Medal, 6.37g, 1911
> George V Coronation Medal, Metal
> Edward VII Coronation Medal 1902, Silver
> Campbell Medical School, Bronze Medal
> Victoria’s Diamond Jubilee Medal, Silver, 83.71g
> Thomason College of Civil Engineering, Roorkee, Silver Prize Medal
> Photographic Society of India, Silver Medal, 78.5g
> Jammu and Kashmir, Bronze Medal
> Hunza-Nagar Badge, Copper, 1891
> Victoria Golden Jubilee, Bronze Medal
> Colonial and Indian Exhibition, London 1886, Copper Medal, 78.95g
```

---

**EDIT:** This code can downloads images.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.todywallaauctions.com/Results.aspx/getSearchResult'

payload = {
    'pageSize':'15',
    'pageTop': '1',
    'whereCondition':'; @MotherCategory = Coins & Paper Money'
}

for page in range(1, 2):
    print('---', page, '---')

    payload['pageTop'] = str(page)
    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    #print(r.status_code)

    data = r.json()
    #print(data.keys())

    text = data['d']
    #print(text[:1500])

    soup = BS(text)
    for item in soup.find_all('dtlotdata'):
        #print(''.join(str(x) for x in item.contents))

        shortdesc = item.find('shortdesc').get_text(strip=True).strip()
        print('> shortdesc:', shortdesc)

        listnumber = item.find('listnumber').get_text(strip=True).strip()
        print('> listnumber:', listnumber)

        lotno = item.find('lotno').get_text(strip=True).strip()
        print('> lotno:', lotno)

        imagecount = item.find('imagecount').get_text(strip=True).strip()
        print('> imagecount:', imagecount)

        number = int(imagecount)
        for x in range(1, number+1):
            filename = '{:>04s}-{:>04s}-{:>02d}.jpg'.format(listnumber,lotno,x)
            url = 'https://www.todywallaauctions.com/PhotosThumb/' + filename
            print(url)
            r = requests.get(url)
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I was accessing the page using selenium webdriver as its a dynamic webpage but with above example we can do it with BeautifulSoup alone.

Comment: With the above approach it is not scrapping the images .

Comment: it is normal. You have to use information from XML to generate links and then use `requests` to get images. It seems you will have to use `listnumber` (176), `lotno` (412) and `imagecount` (2) to generate link to images `/PhotosThumb/0176-0412-01.jpg`, `/PhotosThumb/0176-0412-02.jpg`